DockKit tracking becomes erratic with increased zoom factor in iOS app
I'm developing an iOS app using DockKit to control a motorized stand. I've noticed that as the zoom factor of the AVCaptureDevice increases, the stand's movement becomes increasingly erratic up and down, almost like a pendulum motion. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.
Here's a simplified version of my tracking logic:
func trackSubject(_ boundingBox: CGRect, _ dockAccessory: DockAccessory) async throws {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
          let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) else {
        fatalError("Camera not available")
    }
    
    let currentZoomFactor = device.videoZoomFactor
    let dimensions = device.activeFormat.formatDescription.dimensions
    let referenceDimensions = CGSize(width: CGFloat(dimensions.width), height: CGFloat(dimensions.height))
    
    let cameraOrientation: DockAccessory.CameraOrientation = .landscapeRight // Simplified for example
    
    let cameraInfo = DockAccessory.CameraInformation(
        captureDevice: input.device.deviceType,
        cameraPosition: input.device.position,
        orientation: cameraOrientation,
        cameraIntrinsics: nil, // Currently not providing camera intrinsics
        referenceDimensions: referenceDimensions
    )
    
    let observation = DockAccessory.Observation(
        identifier: 0,
        type: .object,
        rect: boundingBox
    )
    let observations = [observation]
    
    try await dockAccessory.track(observations, cameraInformation: cameraInfo)
}

I'm calling this function regularly (10-30 times per second) with updated bounding box information. The erratic movement seems to worsen as the zoom factor increases.
Questions:

Why might increasing the zoom factor cause this erratic movement?
Should I be providing camera intrinsics to the CameraInformation object? If so, how can I correctly calculate these based on the current zoom factor?
Are there any other factors I should consider when using DockKit with a variable zoom?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Yes, you need to send the intrinsics. Changing the zoom changes the field of view, and since your tracking rectangles are in screen coordinates, you need to know the proper field of view to figure out how much angular change is needed.

Also, I gave up on calling .track() and just directly set the velocity to try to get to the desired position. I wish .track() had worked better for me though.
